# C#: Render object as XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am looking for a way to convert an object tree to XML. It would be fun to write, but I am sure someone has already written it. Here is my wish list:

- It should not care about constructors
- It should ideally handle circular references (not too fussed how)
- It should not require changes to the objects - e.g., no custom attributes
- It should not care about or require known types (e.g., XmlInclude)
- The XML should be dead simple - it needs to be human readable by members of the operations team
- If a property can't be serialized, it should just suppress the error and continue
- Can handle lists and dictionaries

I don't need to reconstruct the object model, so a write-only solution is fine (probably expected).

I think that discounts:

- XmlSerializer - needs parameterless constructors, no circular reference support
- DataContractSerializer - needs attributes (opt in)

Comment: Darned good question! :P

Comment: Interesting question. I'm afraid the "It should not care about constructors" requirements might not be possible to fulfill. How can the serializer know which constructor to use if my type has 10 different constructors?

Comment: @siz -  I should clarify. It doesn't care because it is only serializing (object to XML) and never de-serializing (XML to object). That's what I meant by a 'write-only' solution.

Comment: why would you "rule out" the XmlSerializer, because it is more powerful than you need it to be?  Does that mean you will refuse to use Windows, because it does speech recognition or you will refuse to use a RDBMS because it does geo-spatial now?  Seems like writing this yself is busy work.

Comment: @cheeso i ruled it out because it doesn't fit my scenario. I'm given an object from a third party library. the XmlSerializer cannot handle it (cyclic references, constructors that need parameters, etc.). If you can make the serializer handle the needs above i'd love to see it

Comment: If write-only, it's really a pretty-printer/formatter for arbitrary objects, but outputting in XML.  Maybe search using those terms might help.  BTW does it have to be "XML", or are you really after "human readable"?

Comment: The reason for XML is to log it for the Service Trace Viewer, which provides easy ways to visualize an XML chunk over, say, a regular string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like it would be straightforward to write using reflection: given an object instance, create an XML element with its class name, and then iterate through all of its properties.

For each property create an element with its name:

- if it's a value type, set its text to the XML Schema text of its value;
- if it implements `IEnumerable`, iterate through it and create an element for each item;
- if it's any other reference type, set the element's content to the property's XML representation.

Track circular/multiple references with a HashSet containing the hash codes of each object you've serialized; if you find an object's hash code in the HashSet, you've already serialized it.  (I don't know what you want put into the XML if this happens.)

But no, I don't have any code that does this lying around.

Answer (score 6):

Robert Rossney's post made me think it's probably less work than I thought. So here's a very rough attempt. It handles the following:

- If it is unable to read a property, it prints the exception as the value
- Cyclic references and multiple occurrences. It associates an ID with each element; if an element appears twice, it just points the ref ID. The Ref ID is unique to the object graph (I should probably use a GUID, but this suits my purposes).
- It has no problems with derived types
- It requires no attributes or specific constructors or other nonsense
- It can handle read-only properties

Here's an example of the output (in my test objects, the "Currency" product on the Order throws an exception).

```
<Customer Ref="1">
  <FirstName>Paul</FirstName>
  <LastName>Stovell</LastName>
  <FullName>Paul Stovell</FullName>
  <Orders>
    <Order Ref="2">
      <SKU>Apples</SKU>
      <Price>27.30</Price>
      <Currency>Something bad happened</Currency>
      <Customer Ref="1" />
    </Order>
    <Order Ref="3">
      <SKU>Pears</SKU>
      <Price>17.85</Price>
      <Currency>Something bad happened</Currency>
      <Customer Ref="1" />
    </Order>
    <Order Ref="2" />
  </Orders>
</Customer>
```

Here's the sample object model and usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var customer = new Customer();
    customer.FirstName = "Paul";
    customer.LastName = "Stovell";
    customer.Orders.Add(new Order(customer) { Price = 27.30M, SKU = "Apples"});
    customer.Orders.Add(new Order(customer) { Price = 17.85M, SKU = "Pears"});
    customer.Orders.Add(customer.Orders[0]);

    var output = new StringWriter();
    var writer = new XmlTextWriter(output);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    WriteComplexObject("Customer", customer, writer);
    Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}

class Customer
{
    private readonly List<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();

    public Customer()
    {
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        // Read-only property test
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
    }

    public List<Order> Orders
    {
        // Collections test
        get { return _orders; }
    }
}

class Order
{
    private readonly Customer _customer;

    public Order(Customer customer)
    {
        _customer = customer;
    }

    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Currency
    {
        // A proprty that, for some reason, can't be read
        get
        {
            throw new Exception("Something bad happened");
        }
    }

    public Customer Customer
    {
        get { return _customer; }
    }
}
```

Here's the implementation:

```
public static void WriteObject(string name, object target, XmlWriter writer)
{
    WriteObject(name, target, writer, new List<object>(), 0, 10, -1);
}

private static void WriteObject(string name, object target, XmlWriter writer, List<object> recurringObjects, int depth, int maxDepth, int maxListLength)
{
    var formatted = TryToFormatPropertyValueAsString(target);
    if (formatted != null)
    {
        WriteSimpleProperty(name, formatted, writer);
    }
    else if (target is IEnumerable)
    {
        WriteCollectionProperty(name, (IEnumerable)target, writer, depth, maxDepth, recurringObjects, maxListLength);
    }
    else
    {
        WriteComplexObject(name, target, writer, recurringObjects, depth, maxDepth, maxListLength);
    }
}

private static void WriteComplexObject(string name, object target, XmlWriter writer, List<object> recurringObjects, int depth, int maxDepth, int maxListLength)
{
    if (target == null || depth >= maxDepth) return;
    if (recurringObjects.Contains(target))
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(name);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Ref", (recurringObjects.IndexOf(target) + 1).ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        return;
    }
    recurringObjects.Add(target);

    writer.WriteStartElement(name);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Ref", (recurringObjects.IndexOf(target) + 1).ToString());
    foreach (var property in target.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var propertyValue = ReadPropertyValue(target, property);
        WriteObject(property.Name, propertyValue, writer, recurringObjects, depth + 1, maxDepth, maxListLength);
    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}

private static object ReadPropertyValue(object target, PropertyInfo property)
{
    try { return property.GetValue(target, null); }
    catch (Exception ex) { return ReadExceptionMessage(ex); }
}

private static string ReadExceptionMessage(Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is TargetInvocationException && ex.InnerException != null)
        return ReadExceptionMessage(ex.InnerException);
    return ex.Message;
}

private static string TryToFormatPropertyValueAsString(object propertyValue)
{
    var formattedPropertyValue = null as string;
    if (propertyValue == null)
    {
        formattedPropertyValue = string.Empty;
    }
    else if (propertyValue is string || propertyValue is IFormattable || propertyValue.GetType().IsPrimitive)
    {
        formattedPropertyValue = propertyValue.ToString();
    }
    return formattedPropertyValue;
}

private static void WriteSimpleProperty(string name, string formattedPropertyValue, XmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement(name);
    writer.WriteValue(formattedPropertyValue);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}

private static void WriteCollectionProperty(string name, IEnumerable collection, XmlWriter writer, int depth, int maxDepth, List<object> recurringObjects, int maxListLength)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement(name);
    var enumerator = null as IEnumerator;
    try
    {
        enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
        for (var i = 0; enumerator.MoveNext() && (i < maxListLength || maxListLength == -1); i++)
        {
            if (enumerator.Current == null) continue;
            WriteComplexObject(enumerator.Current.GetType().Name, enumerator.Current, writer, recurringObjects, depth + 1, maxDepth, maxListLength);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString(ex.GetType().Name, ReadExceptionMessage(ex));
    }
    finally
    {
        var disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

I would still be interested to know if there are more tried and tested solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you're going to find anything that works particularly well across all classes. As you pointed out, XmlSerializer is Microsoft's best effort at the generic end of things so far.

On the other end are [visualizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163974.aspx), which are unique to a specific class. I don't think there's much of a happy medium yet.